# Workflow for catalog item

Tags: workflow, servicenow, catalog

CATALOG ITEM

*Manger = existing User list.
*Employee who needs access = existing User list

Workflow after request is submitted:
Short description of the ticket should be the same as the title of the catalog item.

Task A (catalog task)

The catalog task A is assigned to any group to verify if access should be granted. When this task is closed task B is generated.

Task B  (Catalog Task)

Catalog task B is assigned to another group to give access. Once task is closed a notification is sent to both Manager and the Employee listed above. When all tasks are completed then the Request is marked as closed.

can anyone help me to code to send notification to manager and employee variable from above in catalog workflow?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use workflow script on Catalog Task and Approval activities of the workflow

1. Go to catalog task activity and write below script to achieve : "Short description of the ticket should be the same as the title of the catalog item" (for the first task) You could populate Assignment Group accordingly as well

   task.short_description = current.short_description;
2. Go to catalog task activity and write below script to achieve : "Short description of the ticket should be the same as the title of the catalog item" (for the second task) You could populate Assignment Group accordingly as well

   task.short_description = current.short_description;
3. Then go to Approval activity and you can dot walking like this. You could also select the below indicated fields without writing the code

{$request.request_for} and {$request.request_for.manager}